# How to check main blog in a multisite using if statement?

Tags: multisite

I want to create one extra table filed if it is multisite's main blog (While plugin activation).

I mean like this

```
if (main blog) {
  execute this sql;
}
else {
  execute this sql
}
```

PS: This is the code for "execute this sql".

### If child blog:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE tablename (
                  id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                  uid bigint(20) NOT NULL,
                  type VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
                  data TEXT NOT NULL,
                  credits bigint(20) NOT NULL,
                  timestamp bigint(20) NOT NULL,
                  UNIQUE KEY id (id)
                );";
```

### If main blog:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE tablename (
              id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
              uid bigint(20) NOT NULL,
              type VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
              data TEXT NOT NULL,
              credits bigint(20) NOT NULL,
                      globalcredits bigint(20) NOT NULL,
              timestamp bigint(20) NOT NULL,
              UNIQUE KEY id (id)
            );";
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [is_main_site](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_main_site) conditional tag like this:

```
if (is_main_site()) {
  execute this sql;
}
else {
  execute this sql
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check for the $blogid. Main site is 1.

```
global $wpdb;

$mainblog = $wpdb->blogid;

if ($mainblog === 1) {
   execute this sql;
}
else {
    execute this sql
}
```